# Swift minimum implementation for types conforming to protocols with default implementations

Tags: swift

I am trying to make my own type conforming to `CollectionType`. With protocol extensions introduced in Swift 2.0, it is now possible to implement only a subset of the required instance methods and, at the same time, have all other methods implemented automatically. But what is the minimum subset of methods that I need to provide?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the minimum requirement is to implement the
`Indexable` protocol. Here is an example, and none of the 
properties/methods can be omitted without causing a compiler error:

```
struct MyCollectionType : CollectionType {

    var startIndex : Int { return 0 }
    var endIndex : Int { return 3 }

    subscript(position : Int) -> String {
        return "I am element #\(position)"
    }
}
```

The `SequenceType` protocol is implemented by default:

```
let coll = MyCollectionType()
for elem in coll {
    print(elem)
}
/*
I am element #0
I am element #1
I am element #2
*/
```

For a *mutable* collection type, the subscript must be read/write:

```
struct MyCollectionType : MutableCollectionType {

    var startIndex : Int { return 0 }
    var endIndex : Int { return 3 }

    subscript(position : Int) -> String {
        get {
            return "I am element #\(position)"
        }
        set(newElement) {
            // Do something ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:** `CollectionType` has been renamed to
`Collection`, and you have to implement one additional method
which "moves the index" (compare [A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md)):

```
struct MyCollectionType : Collection {

    var startIndex : Int { return 0 }
    var endIndex : Int { return 3 }

    subscript(position : Int) -> String {
        return "I am element #\(position)"
    }

    func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        guard i != endIndex else { fatalError("Cannot increment endIndex") }
        return i + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how about other cases like `SequenceType`? Are there any general ways to figure this out?

Comment: @Peter: That is an interesting question, but I do not have a general answer. What I simply did is to start with an empty implementation: `struct ABC : CollectionType { }` and inspect the compiler messages in the Report navigator. The first error was *"error: type 'ABC' does not conform to protocol 'Indexable'"*. I don't know if that approach works in general.