# How do I know how to conform to a specific protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols

When I declare a class that I want to conform to a protocol, Swift will show me a message saying that I don't conform to that protocol until all of the protocol's requirements have been met.

Is there a way to get the compiler to give me more specific details about which requirements I'm missing or why I'm not conforming to that protocol or do I always have to open the source code for that protocol with my class's source code side by side and do a manual eye-ball comparison?

To clarify, I'm not asking about any specific protocol in particular, in fact I'm really looking for better support in enforcing my own protocols.

Comment: You came from `Ruby`? )

Comment: In Swift you should implement **all** protocol methods and properties unlike in Objective-C. You can copy them from protocol declaration :)

Comment: Probably it is possible to make a Run Script Phase that can do what you need, but I'm not good at scripts.

Comment: @kelin: This is not completely true, protocol methods can have default implementations. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668635/swift-minimum-implementation-for-types-conforming-to-protocols-with-default-impl for an example: You don't have to implement *all* methods listed in `struct CollectionType` in order to conform to that protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Issue Navigator` (exclamation icon on the left side panel, or `CMD+4`) will reveal which protocols are not being conformed to and why:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get the compiler to give me more specific details about which requirements I'm missing?

Yes, the full compiler output tells you exactly which requirements are missing:

- Go to the "Report navigator", <kbd>cmd 8</kbd>.
- Select the last build.
- For each compiled file there is an icon on the right which opens
  the full textual output of the compiler.

Simple example:

```
class A : Equatable {
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error: type 'A' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
class A : Equatable {
      ^
Swift.Equatable:28:17: note: protocol requires function '==' with type '(A, A) -> Bool'
    public func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

Comment: I think the errors listed in the **Issue Navigator** also have a "disclosure" triangle that you can click to reveal the details (in this case, which methods aren't implemented).

Comment: this answer was also helpful, but I'm going with the Issue Navigator solution as the accepted answer because it's slightly more convenient.  

Edit: I've tested this also and found that it's pretty good for checking historical issues, too. i.e., you can check past builds that have failed and see the details of why. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9, helps to implement all mandatory methods of Swift Datasource & Delegates.

Here is example of `UITableViewDataSource`:

Shows warning/hint to implement mandatory methods:

[image]

Click on 'Fix' button, it will add all mandatory methods in code:

[image]