# How to implement MutableCollectionType without crashing the compiler?

Tags: swift

I'm used to an ever-crashing Swift compiler and usually there are plenty of workarounds available. 
This time however I'm not able to successfully make a struct conform to `MutableCollectionType`.

Pasting the attached example into a Playground works as long as you don't uncomment the `MutableCollectionType` conformance.
I avoided concrete implementations for all methods to narrow down the cause of the crash (thus all the `fatalError()`). But even when the methods are implemented properly the compiler will crash.

Does anybody have an idea how to work around this compiler crash?

```
struct Test {}


struct TestCollection: CollectionType {

    typealias Index = Int


    private var values: [Test]


    var count: Int {
        fatalError()
    }


    var endIndex: Int {
        fatalError()
    }


    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<Array<Test>> {
        fatalError()
    }


    var isEmpty: Bool {
        fatalError()
    }


    subscript(bounds: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Test> {
        fatalError()
    }


    subscript(position: Int) -> Test {
        get { fatalError() }
        mutating set { fatalError() }
    }


    var startIndex: Int {
        fatalError()
    }
}


// uncommenting the following line crashes the compiler
// extension TestCollection: MutableCollectionType {}
```

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668635/swift-minimum-implementation-for-types-conforming-to-protocols-with-default-impl for a minimum implementation of (Mutable)CollectionType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, working around compiler crashes is pretty tough. There are a couple of techniques that are helpful, though. First of all, if you compile this and it segfaults (as this is doing for me, currently) you can still go into the error in Xcode, and it might give you more information.

Alternatively, you can try and reduce your crash to the minimum working example, to see which part crashes the compiler. As it happens, the minimum set of methods for `MutableCollectionType` conformance is actually quite small:

```
struct Test {}

struct TestCollection: MutableCollectionType {

  var startIndex: Int { fatalError() }

  var endIndex: Int { fatalError() }

  subscript(position: Int) -> Test {
    get { fatalError() }
    mutating set { fatalError() }
  }

}
```

So now we can add back in your extra things, one by one, until it crashes. As it happens, the `typealias`, `count`, `generate()`, and `isEmpty`, are actually better off being left out. The `typealias` is inferred, `count` and `isEmpty` can be calculated based on the `startIndex` and `endIndex` (and it would be just as efficient as if you wrote your own methods), and the `generate()` method can return an `IndexingGenerator` over the collection itself, rather than the array.

So the only thing to add back in is the ranged subscript:

```
extension TestCollection {
  subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Test> {
    fatalError()
  }
}
```

Looking at that a little more closely, you could possibly write this a little differently:

```
extension TestCollection {
  subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Test> {
    get { fatalError() }
    set { fatalError() }
  }
}
```

And no error!

Just a small note: it *looks* like you're implementing a very lightweight wrapper around `Array`, for your `Test` struct. Because of the complexity involved in properly following all of the required protocols, you *might* be better off just extending `Array` to provide the functionality that you need, or extending `MutableCollectionType` like this:

```
extension MutableCollectionType where Generator.Element == Test {...
```

Comment: Of course the compiler should not crash, but the reason for the error seems to be that `MutableCollectionType` requires a *read-write* `subscript (bounds: Range<Self.Index>)` method, and OP defined a *read-only* method.

Comment: Excellent job narrowing down the cause here! I didn't expect the minimum implementation to be that small. It is very difficult to derive the minimum implementation from the docs and the protocol definitions. -- Also, looking at the docs and the definitions I do now see the hint `{ get set }` for the broken subscript. I wasn't there earlier while the compiler kept crashing and I was surprised that this info was missing. -- And you are right, most implementations will be mapped to a private array instance. But that's fine since I want to hide the implementation details of the struct. -- Thanks!

Comment: This is the result btw :) https://github.com/fluidsonic/JetPack/blob/master/Sources/uncategorized/PhoneNumber.swift